# Android layout color change programmatically

Tags: android, background-color, runnable

I have a class that is supposed to show a screen in white and fade through a lot a colors.

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity implements Runnable {

protected PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

boolean isrunning = true;
int red = 0, blue = 0, green = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) .... etc

TextView btnstart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnstart);
    btnstart.setTypeface(font1);
    btnstart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(
                    getApplicationContext(), R.raw.button);
            try {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            {
                run();
            }
            ;
        }
    });
```

then my runnable

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (isrunning) {

        try {

            red = red + 1;
            blue = blue + 2;
            green = green + 3;
            if (green > 240){

                red = 0;
                blue = 0;
                green = 0;
            }

            LinearLayout colorchanger = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.colorchange);
            colorchanger.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, red, blue,
                    green));
            Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following problem when I press the button the app force closes. If I take out the " while(isrunning)" and replace it with if (isrunning ) it all works but I want the color to keep changing after I click the button.

I´m sure I´m doing something wrong....

Perhaps doing it with a layout is not the best way and I have to do it with a rectangle( size the screen )? and change the color during the onDraw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handlers are well suited for this.

```
// Initialize your handler:
Handler h = new Handler();

// Start fading:
h.postDelayed(color_fade, 0);


// Set up your runnable:     
private Runnable color_fade = new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
      /*
       *  Do your color and layout changes here.
       */
      h.postDelayed(this, 100);  // loop with 100 ms delay.
   }
};
```